# Cant locate or run my script within Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I'm doing exercise 14 of "Learn Python the Hard way" and i have written out my source code, but i can't seem to run the script in either the console within PyCharm, or Powershell. I don't know how to use either and am rather lost.

I tried opening PowerShell and pasting my directory for the file in there but all i got was an error saying

```
PS C:\Users\avalo> F:\Python_Projets\Learning_Python_the_hard_way_excercises\LPTH ex14.py
F:\Python_Projets\Learning_Python_the_hard_way_excercises\LPTH : The term
'F:\Python_Projets\Learning_Python_the_hard_way_excercises\LPTH' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ F:\Python_Projets\Learning_Python_the_hard_way_excercises\LPTH ex14.p ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (F:\Python_Proje...excercises\LPTH:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have no idea what any of that means. Below you can find my source code.

```py
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '> '

print(f"Hi  {user_name}, I'm the {script} scrpit.")
print("I'd like to ask you a few questions")
print(f"Do you like me {user_name}?")
likes = input(prompt)

print(f"Where do you live {user_name}?")
lives = input(prompt)

print("What kind of computer do you have?")
computer = input(prompt)

print(f"""
Alright, so you said {likes}  about liking me.
You live in {lives}. Not sure where that is. 
And you have a {computer} computer, Nice.
""")
```

When i tried to run the script within PyCharm I got the error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/avalo/PycharmProjects/LPTH Excercises/venv/LPTH ex14.py", line 3, in <module>
    script, user_name = argv
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).
```

Comment: The second error indicates that `argv` does not have at least two parts which can be split up in script and user_name. Test whether argv can be split into two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the command and error message:

```
PS C:\Users\avalo> F:\Python_Projets\Learning_Python_the_hard_way_excercises\LPTH ex14.py
F:\Python_Projets\Learning_Python_the_hard_way_excercises\LPTH : The term
'F:\Python_Projets\Learning_Python_the_hard_way_excercises\LPTH' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
```

So, you typed `F:\Python_Projets\Learning_Python_the_hard_way_excercises\LPTH ex14.py` into a Powershell prompt. Powershell tries to make sense of user input, but cannot do that. You see, Powershell thinks there were one command and one parameter - because there was a space. Thus, Powershell's reasoning is like so,

Try to execute `F:\Python_Projets\Learning_Python_the_hard_way_excercises\LPTH`
And pass `ex14.py` as a parameter to the LPTH thing mentioned earlier.

This doesn't make much sense, and there isn't such a thing as `F:\Python_Projets\Learning_Python_the_hard_way_excercises\LPTH`. That's why the error message says that it wasn't recognized as as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program.

This kind of behavior isn't Powershell's own quirk. Cmd shell, Bash and many other need special work-arounds to work with file names that contain spaces.

To work around the issue, you need to use quotes to tell the shell that space is part of file name, not a separator. What's more, you should pass the path as an argument to `python`. The actual path depends on your setup, but it's something akin

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python' 'F:\Python_Projets\Learning_Python_the_hard_way_excercises\LPTH ex14.py'
```

The amperstand is the call operator which will execute python.exe. Note that the parameter .py file is enclosed in single quotes, so that the space will be included as a file name.

Moral of the story: avoid space in file names, unless you are using GUI tools only. Underscore `_` can be used instead of a space to maintain readability. A file name such as `LPTH_ex14.py` wouldn't need any quotes.